# Discord.js copying another bot's embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I want to copy another bot's embed and resend while only changing the image to a thumbnail instead. I've been able to replace the image with a thumbnail, get the author name and footer, as well as the description field. But I have no idea how to get the fields and values. There are a lot of fields and values in the message I'm trying to copy. Do I need to find out exactly how many there are? Here is what I have so far:

```
            let url = e.image.url;
            let desc = e.description;
            let avatar = e.author.name;
            //let avaimg = e.icon.url;
            let field = e.fields.value;
            let field2 = e.fields.name;
            let foot = e.footer.text;
```

then

```
                      embed
                        .setDescription(desc)
                        .setThumbnail(url)
                        .setFooter(foot)
                        .addField(field2, field, true)
                        .setAuthor(avatar)
                      return message.channel.send(embed)
```

and this works, however the fields just say "undefined." So I need a way to get all of the fields and have it repost exactly what it says. Also I'm not sure how to get the author icon.

I hope my question makes sense and I'm sorry if this is a noob question, I am not very experienced with js.

Comment: Maybe try putting the Description, Footer and Field as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MessageEmbed.fields`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=fields) is an array, so you should loop through each element and add them one by one: you can either to this with a `for` loop or using the [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.
Here's an example:

```js
// let's say we have a receivedEmbed and yourEmbed
receivedEmbed.fields.forEach(({ name, value, inline }) => {
  yourEmbed.addField(name, value, true)
})
```

What's happening is that you're looping through every [field](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/EmbedField), grabbing the `name`, `value` and `inline` properties (even if you decide not to use the last one, it' since to know that it exists), and adding to your own embed those same fields.
An alternative would be using a `for` loop:

```js
for (let field of receivedEmbed.fields) {
  yourEmbed.addField(field.name, field.value, field.inline)
}
```

If you're using discord.js@v12, you can also use the [`addFields`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields) method:

```js
yourEmbed.addFields(receivedEmbed.fields)
```